# Question about integral equation formulation of IVPs?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Really embarrassingly stupid question but here it goes:

Consider the mapping:
$Tu(t)=u_0+\int_{t_0}^{t}f(s,u(s))ds$

Why is it that $\left |Tu(t)-Tv(t)  \right | \leq \int_{t_0}^{t}\left |f(s,u(s))ds- f(s,v(s))ds \right |$

How do we know $v_0=u_0$ ?

Comment: Usually you're looking at the space of functions which satisfy the initial condition prescribed by the problem. This is OK for the subsequent use of the Banach fixed point theorem because $(Tu)(t_0)=u(t_0)$ by definition (so $T$ maps this space into itself). That said, even then you should have an inequality, not an equality.

Comment: @Ian ohhhh that makes sense thank you!! But if so why then use the misleading $u_0$ instead of a just a letter constant like a $c$ or something. Also, should I leave the question or delete it afterwards?

Comment: It just depends on how the problem to be solved was previously specified, it could be that $u_0$ was already *defined* to be the initial value for the problem. Also you should leave the question; if I've answered it to your satisfaction then I can write an answer for you to accept.

Comment: @Ian Granted! I am satisfied, could I dare to ask you to pepper in how you correctly deduced that I was looking at the space of functions satisfying the initial condition even though I didn't mention that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, in this setup where you are proving some variant of the existence/uniqueness theorem for ODE IVPs, you are looking at a space of functions which satisfy the initial condition for the problem, i.e. you have a solution space $U$ and for all $u \in U$, $u(t_0)=u_0$. The argument then proceeds by defining $T$ on $U$; fortunately, $T$ maps $U$ into itself (as is necessary for the subsequent use of the Banach fixed point theorem). From these definitions, for any $u,v \in U$, you have

$$(Tu)(t)-(Tv)(t)=\int_{t_0}^t f(s,u(s))-f(s,v(s)) ds$$

from which your statement follows.